# discord.py default errors handling

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

discord.py has it's own error handling, but I need to handle Python error. Example:

```py
def create(a: str, b: str, c: str):
    list = [a, b, c]
    return list

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    a = "First"
    b = "Second"
    list = create(a, b, c)
    await ctx.send(list)
```

on command use i get `Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'c' is not defined` in terminal, but can i handle it with

```py
@client.event
async def on_error(ctx, error):
```

or I need to use `try except` cycle in command?

Comment: you can use you can use the try and except block for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question closed. Answer for this one:

```py
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        if isinstance(error.original, NameError):
            embed.add_field(name = "name", value = "value", inline = False)
```